# Best way to send data through devices? (Android)

Tags: android, database, connection, p2p, voting

Imagine an Android app where you create a poll, you receive a poll code, and when people insert your code, they view your poll, vote on it and you receive the data.

What would be the best way to send this data and save it temporarily? Should I have an external file? A database connection? A p2p connection or anything else?

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for the dumb question I'm completely new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

An Online database will work. You can store the database locally on the phone and have it refresh every "X" amount of time. You will have to use some PHP coding and query the data from the database, sending it back to the phone. You can find a free webhost that lets you store databases [here](https://www.000webhost.com/) . Hope this helps. Also look into importing sqlite database libraries and mysql handlers to implement this. Tweak this example on Youtube to get webhost working and a simple login via php [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M)